# tidyverse:Text file manipulation using some information as final variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I try some a little bit complicated *txt manipulation, but I make some mistakes using the
`tidyverse` package. In my example:

```
#Package
library(tidyverse)

# First a read my data set
myfile<-read_lines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/result_imgall_f_test.txt")

# Look a small piece
# [1] "Start processing imgall/sample_59178.jpg"                         
# [2] "imgall/sample_59178.jpg: Predicted in 7337.640000 milli-seconds." 
# [3] "End"                                                              
# [4] "Start processing imgall/sample_34773.jpg"                         
# [5] "imgall/sample_34773.jpg: Predicted in 7376.639000 milli-seconds." 
# [6] "End"                                                              
# [7] "Start processing imgall/sample_24908.jpg"                         
# [8] "imgall/sample_24908.jpg: Predicted in 7412.858000 milli-seconds." 
# [9] "End"                                                              
#[10] "Start processing imgall/sample_18922.jpg"                         
#[11] "imgall/sample_18922.jpg: Predicted in 7424.998000 milli-seconds." 
#[12] "End"                                                              
#[13] "Start processing imgall/sample_31653.jpg"                         
#[14] "imgall/sample_31653.jpg: Predicted in 7311.578000 milli-seconds." 
#[15] "lca: 90.681282%\tleft_x:   18\ttop_y:   33\twidth:   18\theight:   30"
#[16] "End"                                                              
#[17] "Start processing imgall/sample_17341.jpg"                         
#[18] "imgall/sample_17341.jpg: Predicted in 7418.365000 milli-seconds." 
#[19] "End"                                                              
#[20] "Start processing imgall/sample_11440.jpg"                         
#[21] "imgall/sample_11440.jpg: Predicted in 7365.160000 milli-seconds." 
#[22] "lca: 66.567978%\tleft_x:   54\ttop_y:   34\twidth:   18\theight:   23"
#[23] "lca: 33.219677%\tleft_x:   74\ttop_y:   15\twidth:   23\theight:   22"
#[24] "End"
```

I'd like to create a final data set with just only lca information in a desirable output:

```
#[1] left top width height obj_id        lca
#[2] 54   34  18    23     sample_11440  66.567978
#[3] 74   15  23    22     sample_11440  33.219677   
#[4]  1   38  19    28     sample_40452  66.658073
`
```

Try something like:

```
names_col <- c("left", "top", "width", "height", "obj_id","lca")

mydf <- myfile %>%
  str_subset("lca$") %>%
  enframe(name = NULL) %>%
  separate(col = value, into = names_col, sep = "[\t]") 
mydf
# A tibble: 0 x 6
# ... with 6 variables: left <dbl>, top <dbl>, width <dbl>, height <dbl>, obj_id <dbl>, lca <dbl>
```

without success!! Please, any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to separate on equals signs or commas when you don't seem to have either in your input? At least not within the sample you printed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)

myfile<-vroom("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/result_imgall_f_test.txt",delim = "\t")
myfile <- myfile %>% rename(dados = `Start processing imgall/sample_59178.jpg`)
```

```
myfile %>%
  filter(str_detect(dados, "top|sample")) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(dados, "Predict")) %>%
  separate(dados, c("Start", "obj_id"), sep = "/") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(Start = ifelse(Start == "Start processing imgall",NA,Start)) %>%
  separate(Start, c("lca", "left","top","width","height"), sep= ":  ") %>%
  mutate_all(parse_number) %>%
  fill(., .direction = "downup", obj_id) %>% na.omit() %>%
  select(left, top,width,height,obj_id,lca) %>%
  mutate(obj_id = paste0("sample_",obj_id))
```

```
#  left top width height       obj_id      lca
#1   18  33    18     30 sample_31653 90.68128
#2   54  34    18     23 sample_11440 66.56798
#3   74  15    23     22 sample_11440 33.21968
#4    1  38    19     28 sample_40452 66.65807
```